# Оплата в приложении такси (LiqPay)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, платежи

Пишу приложение для такси (а-ля Uber). Сейчас дошел до этапа безналичной оплаты. Хотелось бы что-то наподобие как сделано в Uber. Смотрю в сторону LiqPay (так как дело происходит в Украине). Вроде бы все нравится, только понять не могу как лучше сделать (интересутет подход **без сертификата PCI DSS**). Писал в поддержку, но ответа не получил...

Если кто имел опыт работы с LiqPay - прошу отозваться.

Пока вижу два пути:

*Путь А:*

1) использовать на клиенте (Android) [checkout](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/aquiring/checkout/) во время "привязки" карты, судя по всему `action = auth`. Полученный токен отправить на наш сервер и там хранить (это вообще правильно?)

2) Для оплаты поездки [использовать полученный токен](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/aquiring/paytoken/), но запрос на оплату по токену уже делать на сервере (что бы деньги были сняты наверняка и не было зависимости от приложения клиента)

3) деньги переводить на единый счет/карту компании

В таком случае было бы удобно использовать [выплаты](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/p2p_credit/) (для последующей отправки денег водителю). Но есть сомнения, что их дадут подключить. Кто-то вообще работал с этим? И что значит первый пункт? (так как явно под два других такси не подходит)

> Какие компании могут подключить API выплат
>
> - компании, оказывающие финансовые услуги клиента, при наличии соответствующего разрешения, согласно законодательства Украины,
> - финансовые компании, зарегистрированные в НБУ,
> - международные сервисы, осуществляющие деятельность в Украине.

*Путь В:*

Использовать [p2p](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/p2p/)

1) Пассажир сначала привязывает карту, как в первом пункет выше.

2) Оплата по номеру телефона или токену водительской карты с использованием токена пассажира.

Второй путь выглядит симпатичнее (деньги уходят сразу куда надо, без промежуточного этапа), но, как я понимаю, нужен сертификата PCI DSS?

Кто имеет опыт работы с LiqPay или реализацией подобных сценариев, прошу ваших советов.

Answer (score 0):

вам не нужен сертификат PCI DSS если вы будете использовать [виджет LiqPay](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/aquiring/widget)

Comment: как его "вставить" в сценарий описаный выше? Что бы клиенту не надо было подтверждать оплату, а она осуществлялась автоматически после завершения поездки?

Comment: @ViT-Vetal- никак. виджет такого не позволяет. Виджет дает возможность самому клиенту оплатить. Насколько я изучил доки и по опыту работы с ликпеем, то там нужен Server-Server запрос. А для него нужен сертификат вроде как.

Comment: @Tsyklop для оплаты по токену необходимо только отправить заявку, в документации про PCI DSS для оплаты по токену ничего не сказано